# Delete all nodes except whitelisted

Tags: javascript, dom

#### What we want

- **Function:** `purgeNodes(root, whitelist)`
- **Action:** Removes all descendants of `root` except those on
  `whitelist` (an array of nodes) [and except descendants of those nodes<sup>9 April</sup>].
- **Returns:** Nothing, or an array of removed nodes, or whatever.

#### Where’s the difficulty?

Blacklist is not a simple negation of whitelist. So it’s not as simple as:

```
function purgeNodes(root, whitelist) {
    var all = [...root.querySelectorAll("*")];
    var blacklist = all.filter(n => ~whitelist.indexOf(n));
    blacklist.forEach(n => n.remove());
    return blacklist;
}
```

In other words, `all != [...blacklist, ...whitelist]`.

Rather, `all == [...blacklist, ...greylist, ...whitelist]`...

<s>...where `greylist` nodes are protected ancestors of `whitelist` nodes but *not* their siblings.</s>

...where `greylist` is an *implicit* array of ancestors and descendants of `whitelist` nodes (but not their siblings) that should be handled like `whitelist` (i.e. not be deleted).<sup>9 April</sup>

Added complexity is the fact that blacklist should rather not contain descendant nodes of other blacklist nodes to prevent redundant deletions. (Deleting an ancestor automatically deletes all descendants.) It’s okay if it does contain them though **if this will vastly simplify** the code.<sup>8 April</sup>

Another land mine are cases when some `whitelist` elements are ancestors/descendants of other `whitelist` elements. Perhaps this could be avoided by requiring the user to eliminate descendant nodes from `whitelist` before passing it to `purgeNodes()`.<sup>9 April</sup>

#### Final words

There are many ways to implement it and I’m keen to see each and any. I’m not sure how I will select answers but I will probably select the most upvoted one, or the oldest one, or optimal code. A **<s>JScript</s> JQuery** answer will *not* be selected as a solution but it’s interesting to see them and they should earn upvotes too. I may or may not post my own answer.

Comment: Are those blacklist, greylist, whitelist identified by some ids?

Comment: @funcoding: They aren’t by default. But a solution that modifies the DOM by adding a CSS class or an HTML attribute to nodes of interest is okay.

Comment: What about text nodes? Should they be deleted if not in the white list? Imagine `<div>abc</div>`, and that this `div` is on the whitelist, but the text node `abc` not, should the `div` be emptied of text?

Comment: @trincot: Not sure. Let’s choose the easier of two tasks. (I can imagine either can be easier depending on paradigm. Handling text nodes is hard in CSS but easy in Javascript.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As became clear in comments and an update to the question, there are two interpretations. One where nodes that have no whitelisted children are removed, and another where those nodes are only removed if they don't have a whitelisted ancestor.

I provide a separate solution for each of these cases.

#### 1. Nodes are removed when they have no whitelisted descendants

```
function purgeNodes(root, whitelist) {
    const hash = new Set(whitelist); // for faster look-up
    const blacklist = [...root.querySelectorAll("*")].reverse().filter( node =>
        !node.children.length && !hash.has(node) && node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
    );
    return blacklist;
}
```

```js
function purgeNodes(root, whitelist) {
    const hash = new Set(whitelist); // for faster look-up
    const blacklist = [...root.querySelectorAll("*")].reverse().filter( node =>
        !node.children.length && !hash.has(node) && node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
    );
    return blacklist;
}

purge.onclick = _ => purgeNodes(document.body, document.querySelectorAll('.white'));
```

```css
div { margin-left: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid; background-color: white }
.white { background-color: pink }
```

```html
<button id="purge">Purge</button>
<div id="a">a
    <div id="b" class="white">b
        <div id="c">c</div>
        <div id="d">d</div>
        <div id="e">e</div>
    </div>
    <div id="f">f
        <div id="g">g</div>
        <div id="h">h
            <div id="i">i
                <div id="j">j</div>
                <div id="k" class="white">k</div>
                <div id="l">l</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="m">m</div>
    </div>
    <div id="n">n
        <div id="o">o</div>
        <div id="p">p</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `reverse()` call is crucial to this algorithm. It relies on the fact that `querySelectorAll('*')` will return the nodes [in document order <sup>w3.org</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#findelements) (emphasis mine):

> The `querySelectorAll()` methods on the `Document`, `DocumentFragment`, and `Element` interfaces must return a `NodeList` containing all of the matching `Element` nodes within the subtrees of the context node, ***in document order***.

See also on [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

> ...depth-first pre-order traversal...

So if you iterate over them in reverse order, you will start with a leaf. If that node is deleted, the parent node might become a leaf. If that parent never becomes a leaf, it means it has a descendant that is on the white list. So the node tree gets trimmed from the bottom up.

This algorithm only regards elements as children, not text nodes and other stuff (comments, ...). So the latter will survive if their container element survives.

#### 2. Nodes are removed when they don't have descendants nor ancestors that are whitelisted

In this case a recursive, top-down algorithm is more suitable:

```
function purgeNodes(root, whitelist) {
    const hash = new Set(whitelist); // for faster look-up
    const recurse = node => hash.has(node) || [...node.children].filter(recurse)[0] 
                                           || !node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    recurse(root);
}
```

```js
function purgeNodes(root, whitelist) {
    const hash = new Set(whitelist); // for faster look-up
    const recurse = node => hash.has(node) || [...node.children].filter(recurse)[0] 
                                           || !node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    recurse(root);
}

purge.onclick = _ => purgeNodes(document.body, document.querySelectorAll('.white'));
```

```css
div { margin-left: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid; background-color: white }
.white { background-color: pink }
```

```html
<button id="purge">Purge</button>
<div id="a">a
    <div id="b" class="white">b
        <div id="c">c</div>
        <div id="d">d</div>
        <div id="e">e</div>
    </div>
    <div id="f">f
        <div id="g">g</div>
        <div id="h">h
            <div id="i">i
                <div id="j">j</div>
                <div id="k" class="white">k</div>
                <div id="l">l</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="m">m</div>
    </div>
    <div id="n">n
        <div id="o">o</div>
        <div id="p">p</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the different output: the nodes *c, d* and *e* are not removed, because *b* is whitelisted.

This function does not return the removed nodes, just a value indicating whether the root still has children after the purge: a falsy/truthy value (not necessarily boolean).

Note that `!node.parentNode.removeChild(node)` is always `false`, because `removeChild` will return the removed element, and the negation (`!`) of that is always `false`. This is to ensure the function returns `false` when it removes the node passed as argument.

`[...node.children].filter(recurse)[0]` will perform the recursion on each of the children, and only keep an array where that call is truthy, i.e. the children that should not be removed. By referencing `[0]` we check if there is at least one such node. I could also have used `.length` or `.length>0`, but `[0]` is shorter and also has a truthy value when it exists, as then it is an object.

Comment: **1.** Impressive Javascript wizardry right there. I have already upvoted your answer but I will take time to assimilate it thoroughly. **2.** Is the order of elements returned by `querySelectorAll()` guaranteed by the specification?

Comment: Yes the order is guaranteed by the specs. I added a quote in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I found a “bug” there... or perhaps a fault in my own question. Your example deletes child nodes of whitelisted `b` (themselves not whitelisted). That’s a behaviour I want to avoid. I wonder how we should modify my question and your answer to avoid this. I fear this little change will ruin your neat algorithm. I wonder what else I forgot to mention (because of taking it for granted) in my question. Sorry for being slow.

Comment: I hate myself for not mentioning it straight away because I love your implementation. I’m thinking that, if including descendants of `whitelist` nodes in implicit protected `greylist` would ruin your method, maybe post an updated solution in a separate answer – and keep this one intact. Maybe.

Comment: I have added a solution for this interpretation to my answer. I kept the original as well, as both could be useful.

Comment: Beautiful. Hoping I didn’t miss anything this time because I’m happy to award the solution checkmark. It’s a pity more people aren’t interested in this problem because your answer deserves more upvotes than just +1 from me. Hopefully more upvotes will come in gradually.